# Hospedar Projeto ASP.NET no IIS na Própria Máquina

Tags: asp.net, iis

Senhores, boa tarde.

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação em ASP.NET C#, e gostaria de hospedar esta aplicação no IIS da minha máquina.

A minha máquina é um windows 7, com IIS 7. Minha internet não é IP fixo, teria que configurar o roteador para aceitar acesso externo.

Gostaria de saber o que devo fazer para conseguir hospedar o meu projeto na minha própria máquina.

Alguém me ajuda?

Answer (score 1):

Não sendo IP fixo, o jeito é usar um serviço de DNS dinâmico como o [NO-IP](http://www.noip.com/pt-BR) ou [Dyn DNS](http://dyn.com/dns/). A maioria dos roteadores já permite a configuração de um desses serviços direto pelo seu utilitário de configurações internas. Essa configuração muda de roteador para roteador, mas geralmente essa basta fornecer seu usuário e senha para que o roteador consiga informar ao serviço de DNS dinâmico quando há uma mudança de IP.

Além disso, no seu roteador, você terá que abrir a porta na qual o seu site estiver rodando (Port Forwarding). Essa configuração muda de roteador para roteador também, mas você terá que informar qual será o IP da máquina e a porta interna (na qual o IIS está rodando) e qual a porta externa (a porta que as máquinas externas à sua rede irão usar). Outro ponto importante é no seu roteador deixar um IP fixo amarrado com o MAC Address da máquina do IIS, de forma a evitar que o DHCP atribua um IP diferente a ela daquele configurado no Port Forwarding.

Também terá que abrir qualquer porta utilizada no Firewall do Windows e/ou do roteador se houver.

Comment: Marcus, tudo bem? Será que você pode me dar uma mãozinha para que eu possa configurar meu computador? Não sou muito bom quando é coisas relacionadas a segurança / infra, gosto mais é de desenvolver mesmo... Caso você queira / pode me ajudar, meu skype é: dimension.ds

PS: Quando eu tiver resolvido este problema, compartilho aqui pra todos!

Comment: To sem acesso ao skype no momento, quando eu tiver disponível, se você já não tiver solucionado, eu te chamo.

Comment: Brother, eu ainda não mexi... Peguei um DNS pra mim com o NO-IP, mas apenas isto... Não tenho mt confiança em mexer nesta parte, por isto posso te aguardar?

Comment: Liberei a porta no roteador, liberei no firewall do windows, criei a conta no no-ip, liberei a porta no modem e ainda continua bloqueado... tenho que liberar em mais algum lugar? To meio perdido ainda...

Comment: Acontece algum erro ou só não acessa?

Comment: Então, tentei acessar por um site que testa se a porta está aberta ou não, e ele sempre da closed... realmente não sei mais o que fazer

Comment: Qual porta está usando? Alguns provedores de internet bloqueiam determinadas portas.

Comment: To setando a porta 10000 como public e 80 como private